# Insert desde un Select con Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Si hago este SQL funciona normal:

```
insert into USR_SISTEMAS VALUES ('16469', '2','3')
```

pero si los datos los quiero traer de un select así:

```
insert into USR_SISTEMAS (SIST_ID, DESCRIPCION, ALIAS) VALUES (select 16469, '2', '3' from dual)
```

o así:

```
insert into USR_SISTEMAS (SIST_ID, DESCRIPCION, ALIAS) VALUES (select 16469 as SIST_ID,'2' AS DESCRIPCION,'3' AS ALIAS from dual)
```

pues simplemente me da el siguiente error:

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 54 del comando -
insert into USR_SISTEMAS (SIST_ID, DESCRIPCION, ALIAS) VALUES (select 16469 as SIST_ID,'2' AS DESCRIPCION,'3' AS ALIAS from dual)
Error en la línea de comandos : 54 Columna : 64
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00936: falta una expresión
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

¿Alguien me ayuda a descifrar por qué es este error?

Comment: el `VALUES` está de más.

Answer (score 5):

Nunca lo he realizado, pero revisando un poco por Internet me encontré con la siguiente estructura:

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... column_n )
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM source_table
[WHERE conditions];
```

En tu caso quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO USR_SISTEMAS (SIST_ID, DESCRIPCION, ALIAS) SELECT 16469 as SIST_ID,'2' AS DESCRIPCION,'3' AS ALIAS FROM dual;
```

Para más información puedes consultar:

> https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php

O esta pregunta de SO en inglés:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323407/insert-select-statement-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 1):

Debes sacar el `Select` del paréntesis, pues no es un valor como tal.

```
INSERT INTO USR_SISTEMAS (SIST_ID, DESCRIPCION, ALIAS) 

SELECT 
    16469 as SIST_ID,
    '2' AS DESCRIPCION,
    '3' AS ALIAS 
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona asi

```
INSERT INTO USR_SISTEMAS  
SELECT 16469, '2', '3' FROM dual;
```

suponiendo que la tabla solo tiene esas 3 columnas.

Answer (score -2):

Indica los campos de la tabla en los que quieres insertar los valores, sino te lo toma como si fueras a insertar los 3 campos en una columna y eso conlleva a un error.

Una forma que seguro te funciona es:

```
insert into USR_SISTEMAS (SIST_ID, DESCRIPCION, ALIAS) VALUES ((select 16469 from dual), (Select '2' from dual), (select '3' from dual))
```

Mete entre paréntesis el `select` de tal forma que `SQL` sepa que el `select` forma parte de un campo y no de varios.

Comment: No hay ningún problema en caso de no indicar los campos que se van a insertar, simplemente se sobreentiende que se van a insertar todos.